# What is the proper way to create shell replacement in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, registry, windows-shell

I am trying to create my own shell that is a shell replacement for Windows. 
I realize that by just setting the value in REGEDIT at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

will works in Windows 7. But, in Windows XP, it's not the case.

If I try to run Windows Explorer, it'll display the taskbar and make itself as the shell for Windows. But in Windows 7, it will just running Windows Explorer, and not displaying its Taskbar

Is there any specific regedit setting needed for a shell replacement in Windows XP?

Comment: The registry location you've shown is indeed how you change the default shell for the current user, even in Windows XP. I don't understand your explanation of how it's not working. Can you give us some more details? Why are you trying to start Windows Explorer if you've changed the default shell?

Comment: @Cody Gay
I am sorry if my explanation is not detail enough. :) What I mean is, if I run explorer.exe in Windows XP with condition that, explorer.exe is not the default shell, it will display its taskbar. It behave like it's the default shell. And surely that's not something I expected for my shell replacement. But it'll not happened in Windows Seven (or maybye Vista too).

I am running Explorer, offcourse to do some file management ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explorer will look at the "Shell" string to see if it does not exist or is != "explorer[.exe]", but it only checks under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE on XP!

If you call one of the undocumented register as shell functions ([SetShellWindow](http://www.freelists.org/post/shell-coding/SetShellWindow), SetProgmanWindow, SetTaskmanWindow, RegisterShellHookWindow etc), explorer will not be able to register itself as the shell since only once process can be the taskbar and desktop shell.

Comment: wow, I just knew that! Surely I'll do a check on that. And give you the result! Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need replace one key in `HKLM` and the other in `HKCU`.
see this for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576.aspx